# Add User to Visual Studio Team Services (Previously Visual Studio Online)

Tags: azure-devops

On the Users tab I'm trying to add a new user but the prompt says "Select user from directory" and when typing an email address to invite it just says "No identities found". This is a newly created account with default settings not linked to any azure subscription.

[image: TFS Users]

The settings show Allow External Guest Access which I assume should allow any microsoft account to be invited.

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the screenshot you provided, your VSTS account is backed by an Azure Active Directory which requires that all users are directory members before they can get access to your Team Services account. So you need to add the user to your AAD first.

"External guest access" is used for external users who are added as guests through Office 365 or added using B2B collaboration by your Azure AD administrator.

> **Q: Can I control access to my Team Services account for external users in the connected directory?**
>
> A: Yes, but only for external users who are added as guests through
>   Office 365 or added using B2B collaboration by your Azure AD
>   administrator. These external users are managed outside the connected
>   directory. To learn more, contact your Azure AD administrator. The
>   setting below doesn't affect users who are added directly to your
>   organization's directory.

Refer to this link for more information: [Team Services: Access with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/manage-organization-access-for-your-account-vs).

Comment: Do you know how to change this to not use Azure AD? I haven't linked it to any azure subscription and have been able to just add users by Microsoft account email addresses before.

Comment: @ChrisSnowden Follow the steps here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/manage-organization-access-for-your-account-vs#disconnect-your-team-services-account-from-azure-active-directory

Comment: That link is just what I needed thanks. Suspected this might have to be done through azure portal.

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT : Can you please help us to resolve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345322/tf400813-the-user-guid-firstnamec-com-is-not-authorized-to-access-this-resou