# VSTS - TF400813: The user 'Guid\FirstName@c.com' is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: azure-devops

We are having problem when accessing the client VSTS.

While Client adding us (FirstName@c.com) as work account it changed to (Eg: EmpId@c.com).
When we tried to accessing VSTS, we where redirected to "c" company network authentication.

After successful login, we are getting error as "TF400813: The user 'Guid\FirstName@c.com' is not authorized to access this resource".

We had tried your best to resolve this issue (Past 1 Week), But access issue still exists.

Note: Client only has administrator permission.

[image]

Can any one help us to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which email address did you use to login the client VSTS account, EmpId@c.com or Guid\FirstName@c.com? And please also confirm with the client, which email (s)he added in this page `https://clientAccount.visualstudio.com/_admin/_users`?

Comment: Client has shared the screen in that EmpId@c.com was there. We tried to login with both FirstName@c.com & EmpId@c.com as work account. But we are getting error as "not authorized".

Comment: What's the access level did the client add the user EmpId@c.com?

Comment: My client will be online post 8.30 PM IST. I will ask my client about this information and screenshot of https://clientAccount.visualstudio.com/_admin/_users. Any other information it's required if any? - Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT : Access Level for "EmpId@c.com" is "Visual Studio Subscriber"

Comment: Sorry for the delay since I was out of office for last two days. I added an answer you can refer. And it's recommend to use a Microsoft email address.

Comment: I will request my client to add Microsoft account. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is mainly caused by the VSTS account is not connect with the AAD which your user account EmpId@c.com stored in.

Since the email address EmpId@c.com is not a Microsoft email, it will be backed to AAD when connecting the VSTS account. If the client VSTS is not connected this AAD or connected with another AAD, you will not be authorized to login the client VSTS account.

In order to connect the client account, you can follow any of the be options:

#### Option 1: connect VSTS to Azure AAD

Detail information about connect VSTS account to AAD, you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/connect-account-to-aad).

#### Option 2: use Microsoft email login your client VSTS account.

You can use a Microsoft email address (such as user@outlook.com or user@hotmail.com etc) instead the address EmpId@c.com. And ask the client to add the Microsoft email to the VSTS account. It’s easier and recommend way.