# TF400813: Azure DevOps is not authorized

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-deployment-slots

1. az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/XXXX
   token 
   able to login
2. AZ Login - Successfully connected to Azure
3. Try to run 
   az devops project list
   TF400813: The user '1a6dbb80-5290-4fd1-a938-0ad7795dfd7a\xx.yyyy@abc.com' is not authorized to access this resource.

I have full access to this organisation,still not able to access

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar thread: [TF400813: The user 'Guid\FirstName@c.com' is not authorized to access this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345322/vsts-tf400813-the-user-guid-firstnamec-com-is-not-authorized-to-access-thi)

Please make sure the organization is connected to AAD and your account is one of the users in this AAD.

Also try to use a microsoft email address instead of XXXX@abc.com see if you can get authorized.